# What is the Difference between change company and cross company in Microsoft Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

What are the differences between change company and cross company in Microsoft Dynamics AX?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was obviously not a question in the first place if the OP is answering it within a minute

Comment: Maybe he spent a bunch of time trying to figure this out and wanted to share his findings. If it can help someone in the future then it's worth keeping otherwise close it.

Comment: I partially agree if this would be a real problem which is hard to tackle but in this case it is rather a question about basic understanding of a concept which is documented on MSDN - which you can find via simple search by your fav. search engine. IMHO if at all, his answer would be a case for SO documentation (beta).

Answer (score -1):

Both are used to fetch the data from any company (irrespective of which company AX is point to)

But there are few differences

1. crosscompany used as a keyword in the select statement
   changecompany used as block. (means all the code should be in the curly braces e.g. changecompany("USMF"){...sql queries and code...})
2. crosscompany is used only for select statements
   changecompany is used for select, insert, update and delete
3. No need to speciy any company for cross company. it fetches data for all the companies by default. Also, cross company can be limited to desired companies, by using container
   need to specity company name for change company and only once company can be specified. more than one company is not possible in case change company